# Как сделать отображения статуса пользователей сайта (на сайте/не на сайте)

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня появилась необходимость сделать такую штуку. К примеру, пользователь зашел на сайт и у меня показалось, что он онлайн. Как только он вышел, показалось, что он оффлайн. Предложите какую-либо идею.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте в БД таблицу online

Поля id, time

На сайте делаете простой js скрипт который раз в 30 секунд будет посылать к серверу запрос вида

```
<script>
    check_active();

    function check_active(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://myhost.com/check_online/?id=%USER_ID%"
        });

        setTimeout("check_active()", 30000);
    }
</script>
```

На сервере обновляете таблицу online для id записываете текущую метку времени. При показе пользователя просто смотрите, если текущее время больше чем time таблицы + 30 значит пользователь оффлайн.

Можно, просто, добавить поле time в таблицу пользователей.

Это если нужно очень часто обновлять состояние активности пользователя. Если же такого не требуется, то можно просто при перезагрузке страницы обновлять статус

Если вам требуется, что бы вам приходило уведомление о том, что пользователь зашел на сайт - то делаете все то же самое, но кроме этого делаете второй скрипт, который будет работать в вашем (как я понял административном) интерфейсе. Этот скрипт должен проверять наличие новых пользователей, которые зашли с того момента как последний раз проводилась проверка. Понятно? Или разъяснить поподробнее?

Comment: В таблицу пользователей его добавлять точно ненадо... Это решение нормальное если активность пользователей онлайн это все что необходимо... Кстати - еще можно посылать id=0 например если пользователь неавторизован и считать, так-же, сколько на сайте "зайцев" :) Только тогда надо будет както их рзличать, но это можно сделать например передав идентификатор сессиии

Comment: То, что добавлять в таблицу пользователей не стоит это понятно. Я поэтому сразу и описал, что надо создать новую)

Насчет id=0 - идея хорошая)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого используется работа с сессиями, если быть более точным - в бд создается таблица в которую ложится время активности того или иного пользователя, т.е. при любом его действии на странице мы обновляем поле **last_activity**, Скриптом же мы выбираем, например всех пользователей которые проявляли свою активность в течении 10 минут от текущего времени. Если же нужна реально достоверная информация о том кто онлайн(не по 10и минутке), то сессия обновляется аяксом каждую, например, минуту, соответствено выборка уже идет по активности за последнюю минуту, вообще почитайте о работе с сессиями в бд, сразу куча идей появится :)